# Connecting to a remote python server from Android

Tags: android, server, client, remote-server

I am working on a simple messaging app. The very first page of the app is a log in screen. It utilizes an Credentials and Client class to allow access. The code is failing before it gets into the Credentials class. Here is the code

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.mchat.messagingapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.mchat.messagingapp.Credentials;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import com.mchat.messagingapp.Credentials;
import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

}
int attempts = 3;

// The login button has been clicked
public void onButtonClick(View view) {

    EditText PW_ = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText ID_ = findViewById(R.id.ID);

    //Some hashing stuff was here

    //Run server request to get user data
    try {
        Credentials c = new Credentials();
        Client client = new Client("myipaddress",PORTNUM); //random values for question
        ServerMessage message = client.readServerMessage();

        client.sendMessage(ClientMessageType.LOGIN, ID_.getText().toString());
        message = client.readServerMessage();
        System.out.println(message.getMessage());
        c = ReadMessage.returnCred(message.getMessage());
        System.out.println(c.getUsername());


    // loging in
    if (c.getLocked() == "1") {
        if (hassedPass.equals(c.getPsword())) {
            if (c.getAdmin() == "1") {
                //go to admin page
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminList.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            } else {
                //go to normal page
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mainpage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            attempts--;
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Login, " + attempts + " attempts remaining", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), c.getLocked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "ACCOUNT LOCKED! Please go see Tech Support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    } catch (ClientException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void on_login(View view) {

    if(attempts > 0) {
        onButtonClick(view);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Too many failed attempts",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

}
```

### Client.java

```
package com.mchat.messagingapp;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client
{
private Socket serverSock;
private BufferedReader inStream;
private BufferedWriter outStream;

public Client(String server, int port) throws ClientException
{
    try
    {          
        this.serverSock = new Socket(server, port);

        this.inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.serverSock.getInputStream()));
        this.outStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.serverSock.getOutputStream()));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new ClientException("Encountered an error while initializeing client!", e);
    }
}

public void close() throws ClientException
{
    try
    {
        this.sendMessage(ClientMessageType.HANGUP);
        this.serverSock.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new ClientException("Encountered an error while closing client connection!", e);
    }
}

public ServerMessage readServerMessage() throws ClientException
{
    try
    {
        String message = this.inStream.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server sent: " + message);

        this.sendMessage(ClientMessageType.ACK);

        return new ServerMessage(
                ServerMessageType.getMessageType(message.substring(0, 10)),
                message.substring(10));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new ClientException("Error reading message from server!", e);
    }
}

public void sendMessage(ClientMessageType message) throws ClientException
{
    this.sendMessage(message, null);
}

public void sendMessage(ClientMessageType message, String extraText) throws ClientException
{
    try
    {
        if(extraText != null)
            this.outStream.write(message.getMessage() + extraText + '\n');
        else
            this.outStream.write(message.getMessage() + '\n');

        this.outStream.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new ClientException("Message could not be sent to server!", e);
    }
}

}
```

When running this code in Intellij (minus the android stuff), it works great. But once i run the same client commands in Android studio, it breaks. I know it is not a firewall or port forwarding issue. The LogCat gives this everytime i run it `I/System.out: com.mchat.messagingapp.ClientException: Encountered an error while initializeing client!` It seems like it isn't even reaching the server. I believe the error is in using Android, but i cannot find where it is breaking. I appreciate any and all help and will gladly provide any more info as needed.

Comment: There must be more error logs. can you please post that?

Comment: Since it is ran, only when i click on the button, this is all it outputs in LogCat

Comment: 12-11 23:52:13.768 4212-4212/com.mchat.messagingapp I/System.out: com.mchat.messagingapp.ClientException: Encountered an error while initializeing client!
12-11 23:52:13.780 1254-1281/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xaf583200) throttle end: throttle time(11)
12-11 23:52:13.792 1254-1281/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xaf583200) throttle end: throttle time(11)

Comment: We cannot help with only this much information. 1) have you added necessary permissions? 2) Note that you cannot run network related operations in a UI thread, you should move them to a worker thread.

Comment: This is all ran on a `OnButtonClick()` , do i need to change that?

Comment: no. just wrap the code it in a worker thread. I am not sure if its the actual issue. without the actual error log I can't tell anything for sure